# Organizar contenido DIV

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, div

No soy capaz de encontrar solución al alineamiento/organización del contenido de mis div's con Bootstrap. No acabo de entender el funcionamiento de

```
aling-items-*
text-*
aling-self-*
justify-items-*
justify-self-*
```

Estoy tratando de organizar mi web de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no soy capaz de alinear los contenidos para que se junte del todo a los bordes derecho o izquierdo o para que quede el contenido ya sea img, texto u otro div en el centro del mismo. Quisiera evitar utilizar padding o margins ya que estoy tratando de hacer un contenido responsive y luego pueden darme otros problemas. Muchas gracias por su ayuda, un saludo.

```
<div class="row text-center">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a href="inicio.html">
      <img src="img/elementos/logo-lg.svg">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a>Planifica, viaje, comparte</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a>Planea tu proximo viaje</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a>Explora e inspírate</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="row text-right">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a href="#">Google</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-right">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a href="#">Descarga la aplicación</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Saludos. Incluye el código de lo realizado; entre otras cosas para comprender si es un `div` principal (el color rosado) que contendra 3 `div` ocupando 4 columnas (los   azules) y cada uno de estos un contenido que será una imagen a la izquierda, un texto al centro y otra `div` a la derecha. Tu código servirá para guiar o detectar lo que falta/sobra.

Answer (score -1):

Por favor intenta con esto, por el momento quiero que vayas experimentando con las clases, y si puedes verifica la [Documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark p-2">
    <div class="row bg-light p-2">
        <div class="col-4 bg-danger">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 bg-primary">
                    <a href="#"><img src="./media/logo" alt="img-logo"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-success">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 m-auto">
                    <p class="bg-warning">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, quis?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-secondary">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-sm-9 col-sm-3 bg-primary">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```